# JButton - How to connect?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jbutton, actionlistener

I found this code online and modified it and it stopped working. I'm thinking it has something to do with when I added the Jpanel but what I am doing works best with a JPanel. How do I make it that the events in the action performed if statements work?

```
    import java.awt.GridLayout;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
    import java.util.*;

    import javax.swing.*;

    public class GUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    static JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(5, 5, 1, 1));

    public GUI() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        //setSize(100, 100);
        //setLocation(100, 100);



        //Button 1
        JButton button1 = new JButton("1");
        button1.addActionListener(this);
        panel.add(button1);

        //Button 2
        JButton button2 = new JButton("2");
        button2.addActionListener(this);
        panel.add(button2);

        //Button 3
        JButton button3 = new JButton("3");
        button3.addActionListener(this);
        panel.add(button3);

        //Button 2
        JButton button4 = new JButton("4");
        button4.addActionListener(this);
        panel.add(button4);

        //Button 2
        JButton button5 = new JButton("5");
        button5.addActionListener(this);
        panel.add(button5);

        //Button 2
        JButton button6 = new JButton("6");
        button6.addActionListener(this);
        panel.add(button6);

        //Button 2
        JButton button7 = new JButton("7");
        button7.addActionListener(this);
        panel.add(button7);

        //Button 2
        JButton button8 = new JButton("8");
        button8.addActionListener(this);
        panel.add(button8);

        //Button 2
        JButton button9 = new JButton("9");
        button9.addActionListener(this);
        panel.add(button9);



        panel.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new GUI();
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Calc");
        f.setContentPane(panel);
        f.setSize(1000, 1000);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setVisible(true);

    }

    ArrayList numbers = new ArrayList();
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String command = e.getActionCommand();

        if (command.equals("button1")) {
            myMethod();
            numbers.add(1);
            System.out.println("1");
        }
        if (command.equals("button1")) {
            numbers.add(2);
            System.out.println("2");
        }
    }

    public void myMethod() {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Hello, World!!!!!");
        System.out.println("Hey");
    }
}
```

Comment: When you say it stopped working, what happened? What have you tried yourself to diagnose the problem and what were the results of those attempts?

Comment: I have tried changing the if statements and tried running methods from the if. What happens right now is that it seems like the buttons are not working at all. The println isn't being printed to the console. Im before that it ran the pop up box from myMethod.

Comment: Just tried changing that code and all I get is an an error saying button1 cannot be resolved to a variable. Ill play with that for a little.

Comment: The setActionCommand worked. If you post as an answer, I will mark it as correct. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the part **actionPerformed** as:

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
     String command = e.getActionCommand();

        if (command.equals("1")) {
            myMethod();
            numbers.add(1);
            System.out.println("1");
        }
        if (command.equals("2")) {
            numbers.add(2);
            System.out.println("2");
        }

}
```

Here, when a button is clicked, your e.getActionCommand() will give the constructor string. i.e. "1", "2" ,"3" and so on

[reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionEvent.html#getActionCommand%28%29)

Answer (score 1):

I put comments in code, but the first thing you should do is to read official tutorials. [How to use Buttons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html)

```
    public class GUI /*extends JFrame implements ActionListener*/ {
         //don't extend JFrame is you don't have too neither implement ActionListener in top-container classes that breaks single responsability principle      
    private JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(5, 5, 1, 1)); // why static??           

    public JPanel getPanel(){
        return panel;
    }

    public GUI() {            
         //i use anonymous classes for this, then you don't have to use if-else        

        //Button 1
        JButton button1 = new JButton("1");
        button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
           @Override
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
               myMethod();
               numbers.add(1);
               System.out.println("1");
           }
        });
        panel.add(button1);

        //Button 2
        JButton button2 = new JButton("2");
        button2.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
           @Override
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
              //put here logic for button2
           }
        });
        panel.add(button2);            
        //and goo on with other buttons    
       //panel.setVisible(true); you don't need to call this!!       
    }

   /**
     * Create the GUI and show it.  For thread safety, 
     * this method should be invoked from the 
     * event-dispatching thread.
     */
    private static void createAndShowGUI() {     
        //Create and set up the window.
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        GUI gui = new GUI();
        frame.add(gui.getPanel());

        //Display the window.
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
        //creating and showing this application's GUI.
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI(); 
            }
        });
    }

    private List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();//use generics! 


    public void myMethod() {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Hello, World!!!!!");
        System.out.println("Hey");
    }
}
```